# MYSQL Procedure call is not returning anything in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a MYSQL Procedure to fetch employee details. The calling procedure is

```
function call_procedure($procedure)
{
    require_once("database_connect.php");
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
    $result = $mysqli->query("CALL $procedure");
    return $result;
}
```

I call this function from another page by using this function:

```
function get_emp_details($parameters){
    //create the query
    $procedure = "fetchEmpDetails($parameters)";

    $result = call_procedure($procedure);

    // check for empty result
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response['DATA'] = sqltoarray($result);
        // success
        $response['RESULT'] = 0;
        $response['MESSAGE'] = 'Employee Details found';
        $response['REQUEST'] =1;
    } 
    else {
        $response['DATA'] = '';
        // no products found
        $response['RESULT'] = 1;
        $response['MESSAGE'] = "Incorrect Employee ID";
        $response['REQUEST'] =1;
     }

    // echo no users JSON
    return $response;
}
```

When I am using both the functions in the same file it is working fine. However, when I am using the two functions in different files, I am not getting any results when calling get_emp_details function.

To debug, I tried to echo values of $procedure and $result. The string in $procedure is as expected, but the value I am receiving in $result is nothing.

The login() function which is also defined in the same file as the get_emp_details() function is working fine. It is the get_emp_details() that is causing the problem.

Can anyone help me with this?? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: when they're in separate files, did you include/require the code for the second file into the first one?

Comment: Yes, we have added the require_once () . In the second file